# How to raise validation errors from Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, request, recaptcha

I am dealing with some weird stuff. I am looking at `request.env['recaptcha.valid']` a special key I added to the request variable available only to Rails controllers.

Depending on the state of the above variable, how can I raise a rails validation error from the Rails controller rather than dealing with this logic in the Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `before_filter`, which can choose to render or redirect, or simply set some internal state (`@captcha_failed = true`) before your action is invoked.

You might want something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :check_captcha

  # ...

  protected

  def check_captcha
    if params[:captcha] != request.env['recaptcha.valid']
      redirect_to "index", notice: "Invalid captcha"
    end
  end

end
```