# Adding a validation error in a controller in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a controller I have a code which isn't associated with the model directly:

```
def create

  var1 = get_some_post_param
  # check if var1 isn't nil -- how to add an error the model if it is?

  # some other code...
  @m = Model.new(field1: var1, field2: var2, field3: var3)
  if @m.save
    # ok
    #....
  else
    # error
    ...
  end
end
```

How can I add a validation error to the model right after `var1 = get_some_post_param` if `var1` is nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you can directly do that in your controller.

You can associate the non-model `var1` attribute to any one of your model attribute (this can be a new attribute for this purpose, say: `special_var1`).

Then in your controller you can have:

```
  before_action :set_special_var1

  def set_special_var1
    var1 = get_some_post_param
    @m.special_var1 = var1
  end
```

And, then in your model, you can add a custom validator:

```
# model.rb
validate :special_var1_is_not_nil

private

def special_var1_is_not_nil
  if self.special_var1.nil?
    errors.add(:special_var1, 'special_var1 is nil')
  end
end
```

Or, you can also try:

```
validates :special_var1, allow_nil: false
```

However, these validations will be invoked before the object is being persisted e.g. when you call: `@m.save`, not before that.

#### Update

The best you can do in your controller is, having a `before_action` in your controller and then redirect to some page if `var1` is `nil`:

```
before_action :check_var1

private

def check_var1
  var1 = get_some_post_param
  unless var1
    redirect_to "index", notice: "Invalid var1"
  end
end
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476227/how-to-raise-validation-errors-from-rails-controller) for some reference.

Comment: I need to return a validation error right after get_some_post_param if the value is invalid, do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Well, validation error will be generated and returned once you call the `@m.save` in this case, not before that. You can't just call that manually in your controller, at least I don't know if that's possible at all.

Comment: So, yeah, I don't think you can raise validation error from your model. Look at my updated code. This is best you can do in your controller I think. Also, see this post which is kind of similar to your post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476227/how-to-raise-validation-errors-from-rails-controller